# My 908S soldering iron died

Tags: pcb, resistors, soldering-iron-station

I bought a 908S soldering iron from AliExpress.  It was great until a resistor exploded.

Can someone help me find a picture of the PCB so I know what resitor to use to replace it?

I can't identify it because the cover is gone.

[image]

Comment: I feel like I would be concerned as to why the resistor failed. Maybe it was a resistor meant to limit the current on the iron and wasn't sized properly??

Comment: The resistor is all but certainly not the original failure.  The TRIAC would be a more likely suspect, and killed the resistor too...

Comment: What form of product guarantee did you receive from Aliexpress? What brand name was the product? What data sheet did it come with? What spares support do Aliexpress provide? What customer services (aftercare) can Aliexpress give you? How much did you pay? Did you ever consider buying a soldering iron from a dealer with any form of reputation selling branded goods from a reputable or recognized manufacturer of soldering equipment?

Comment: @Andyaka You need to get a rubber stamp made :-). MAybe we need a canonical Q&A relating. Probably a good idea. No?

Comment: As Chris says - the Triac may be dead. | Without more information it is not possible to be sure but a 100k resistor will probably do no harm. May do no good also. If you can get a circuit diagram (with or without component vaklues) it will help.

Comment: Yes, I thinks it's a good idea @RussellMcMahon

Comment: They are less then $20.00 why not get another and see what it is. At that price I would consider it disposable.

Comment: On my 908s pcb the resistor says: 1R00

Comment: Try this Schematic maybee help :)
http://tnweb.tode.cz/oprava-pajecky-908s-80w/

Comment: Mine has 1 Ohm there as well. As @Macron0 says, it's labeled 1R00.
Schematic diagram from Czech site (linked by @Ondrej) confirmes that (R2).
Take a bunch of them and replace one. It's a quick test. If it doesn't help or it burns again then follow the triac path as suggested above.
I find comments suggesting to buy another one just useless. OP could do this without community's advice.